# Get Multiple Toggle Button values on the basis of id in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to get value of toggle button as yes or no .. since there are so many questions coming dynamically .I want to get this of basis of item.id .. I am using Angular and Required to write the logic in TS file . Any help will be appreciated

My Html:-

```
                  <div class="form-group">
                     {{item.id}}.<label>{{item.question}}</label>
                      <label class="switch">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn" (change)="getToggleButtonValue($event)">
                      <div class="slider round">
                        <span class="on">ON</span>
                        <span class="off">OFF</span>
                      </div>
                    </label>
```

Comment: where are you attaching the event of click for the toggle button?

Comment: check now I have attached change event

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div class="form-group">
             {{item.id}}.<label>{{item.question}}</label>
             <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" id="togBtn" #toggles data-id="{{item.id}}">
            <div class="slider round" >
             <span class="on">ON</span>
             <span class="off">OFF</span>
             </div>
            </label> 
            </div>
```

ts:

```
@ViewChildren("toggles") toggles: QueryList<ElementRef>;

getToggleByID(id) {
  let value = null;
  this.toggles.forEach(item => {
      if(item.nativeElement.getAttribute('data-id') === id){
         value = item.nativeElement.value;
      }
    });
  return value;
}
```

Comment: getting error Type 'QueryList<ElementRef<any>>' is not an array type or a string type

Comment: I'm sorry, I fixed it

Comment: ok Thanks .. but when I be able to get the value  any event for this...can u just keep console.log for output value

Answer (score 0):

You should to attach the event of click for the toggle button. For example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hx9czl

Comment: what if we have multiple items

Comment: I have changed project in stackbitz for multiple items.